# Password protected office files fail to upload using Attachment API

Tags: servicenow

I am using ServiceNow Attachment API - POST /now/attachment/upload. This is working fine for all file types configured in Security properties. However it does not work when an attempt is made to upload a password protected office file, say Excel for example. I have tried uploading such file/s through their REST API Explorer as well as list item form with no luck.

When upload through SN form, the error received is "File mime type does not match the file content". SN form by always posts data as "application/octet-stream" however my upload script does set proper content-types and still fails. If content-type was the problem, it shouldn't have worked for unprotected file/s too.

**Update**

When I try to upload using REST API Explorer, it gives error for incorrect content-type. Same file without password works well. See screen shots below:

*api/now/attachment/file*

[image]

*api/now/attachment/upload*

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting MIME Type validation to false did the trick. This was acceptable in our case because we wanted to run PowerShell script that moved (uploaded) attachments from existing system to SN as part of data migration activity. It should ideally be turn on (true).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can upload password protected excel files to ServiceNow. Here is a snap shot where I uploaded a password protected attachment from REST API Explorer to an incident record. The content type really does not matter.

[image]

Comment: Tried on `incident` table too with no luck. See **update** in question. Is there any setting in ServiceNow that I need to enable?

Comment: I have tried OOB on geneva, istanbul with same file type as your's and password protected - Content-Typeapplication/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet. It works. Is your instance OOB? Can you try a different sample file?